# Roles and Capabilities in Custom Post Types

Tags: custom-post-types, capabilities, user-roles

Is there a way to create one role with one capability and apply it to some of the custom post types?

What I am doing right now is ending up with applying capabilities to all of the posts..

creating role:

```
$wp_roles->add_role( 'member', 'Paid Membership', array(
'has_paid' => true,
'has_registered' => true
) );
```

creating a custom post type (i use a class but you ll get the idea)

```
AN_Posts::AddPostType( static::post_type, array( 'Group', 'Groups', 'groups' ), array( 'description' => 'A user group', 
'map_meta_cap' => true, 
'capability_type' => 'an_group', 
'capabilities' => array( 'read_post' => 'has_registered',
) ) );
```

check permission

```
if ( is_single() && ! current_user_can( 'read_post', $post->ID ) )
    $wp_query->is_404 = true;
```

Any ideas where i am doing it wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to [`register_post_type()` documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) `capability_type` argument is used to construct capabilities.

I think since you are customizing it for the post type, its capabilities requirements won't be formed like `read_post` but like `read_an_group`.